# xsl conditon check in apply template

Tags: xslt

my xsl is like

```
<root>
    <tests>
        <test id="222">
         <actionId>233</actionId>
        </test>
        <test id="22">
         <actionId>23333</actionId>
        </test>
    </tests>
    <confs>
        <conf id="2211"></conf>
    </confs>
</root>

    <xsl:key name="confId" 
        match="confs/conf" 
        use="@id" /
<xsl:template match="main">
Test:
<xsl:apply-templates select="tests/test" />
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="tests/test">
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="actionId[.='']">
                <li>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="key('confId', @id)">
                            Used </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise> Not found</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </li>
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise> <li>Not at all found</li></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

right now 'Not at all found' message is printed on every iterations for this template match as actionId is not null,which i need to print it only once if the conditon is not executed.

Expected Output is

Not at all found

is printed only once when actionId in the tests/test template never finds a match, ie

Not at all found

is not iterated in the template

Comment: I'd say: check the condition before you execute the template and print it there.

Comment: but i m iterating the node to check the condition in test template

Comment: Incomplete code and lack of any source XML -- how do you imagine people will be able to understand whatever you are asking? The reason for the observed behavior could be explained if the complete code and source XML document were provided. We need to see the definition of the key and how the template is selected for execution. Please, edit the question and provide the missing information.

Comment: Can you show your expected output too, please?

Comment: Output is <li>Not at all found</li> is printed only once  when actionId[.=''] in the template never finds a match, ie <li>Not at all found</li> is not iterated

Comment: You should edit your question with your expected output, as that would make it easier to read. Also, you refer to "actionId" in the XSLT, but this does not exist in the XML. Could you provide a larger sample of XML, preferably one with multiple **test** elements, because at the moment there is only one, and so your message is only ever going to get printed once anyway. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately my xsl code is very large,so i needed to create sample xml.hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Each time the match="test" template is activated, it can only use information available via the test element in the source document, or via the template parameters, or global variables. It can't use any knowledge of previous activations, because XSLT is stateless.

If you want to handle the first test element differently from other elements, then write two different template rules.

If you want to handle the first test element with actionId[.=''] specially, then write a template rule that matches it:

```
<xsl:template match="test[actionId[.=''][1]">
```

Comment: i had tried with two different template rules,but each time it finds a test element it prints the Not at all found message which should be printed only once like   what i had tried is like <xsl:template match="test[actionId[.='']]"> and <xsl:template match="test[actionId[.!='']]">

Comment: any other options that i try for will be more helpful